# using html_escape and auto_link on same variable in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, variables, codeigniter-2, htmlspecialchars

I want to display user comments on my site and I am escaping the output using html_escape (htmlspecialchars in Codeigniter). But I also want to activate URLs in the comments using Codeigniter's auto_link function.

**How can I apply both functions to the same variable/content?**

```
<?php echo html_escape($review); ?>

<?php echo auto_link($review); ?>
```

I have to use html_escape, because I don't trust the user content; but I would like to show URLs entered, if possible. Note: there is no conflict between the characters in html_escape and in auto_link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`auto_link(html_escape($review))`

However, if you don't trust your users, don't parse their links. Assuming your users provide insightful comments like

> Free cheap drugs at http://example.com/

`auto_link(html_escape($review))` will still parse the link.

Comment: Accepted and upvoted. So simple, yet so far away from my brain right now--time for a day off. [removed rest of comment]